# laravel 4 blank page on live server - 500 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

My laravel site is working correctly on my local apache server and WAS working correctly on my remote live/development server. I carried out an ftp sync last night and now all I can get is a blank white page.

In the console I can see an error status 500 internal server error

I've read similar posts on this suggesting folder permissions and using filezilla I have set the permissions on all files and folders to 777 - I've also tried 775.

I've deleted all the remote files and re-uploaded them (and set permissions again).

I've checked the .htaccess settings (which are standard)

No log files are being created

I'm not sure what I can check next - can anyone help please

Thanks

Comment: If I were you I'd check the log files (PHP error log, Laravel log and maybe even Apache log, though that's likely to be useless).

Comment: You're working on L3 or L4?

Comment: Don't you have a version manager (Git, SVN) ? If so you can check what have changed since the previous deployment. If not, you should think about it for the rest of your project. Anyway, if you can, try to restore your app to the previous state and redo your changes step by step, it's a good debugging strategy.

Comment: Hi. Using laravel 4.1 I'm using git but not sure that will help as it was effectively a redeployment onto the live/deployment server.  I'll look at the log files next although the laravel ones aren't being updated on the live server. The site works fine on my testing local server

Comment: @Ray..I have the same issue...did you ultimately get it to work?

Comment: Yes. I deleted everything from the live server and re-uploaded. One of the errors I discovered was case sensitivity on the live server but not on my development. 
Also I enabled php error reporting on the page.
If it's a blade page I find these difficult to debug but commented out blade variables etc in turn.